# CSS transitions creates white border issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. I found these two topics that seem to have the same issue. But I have not been able to solve it with the tricks mentioned in them.

[1px white spacing in Chrome between div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983212/1px-white-spacing-in-chrome-between-divs)

[overflow: hidden is causing white border with css transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316703/overflow-hidden-is-causing-white-border-with-css-transition)

When I applied Css transitions to the code, these small white borders started to appear on some of the divs. They only appear in certain window sizes. And I can't get rid of them. Can anyone please help me? I have tried to put everything from overflow:hidden; to -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; in different places of the css. But nothing has worked, and I am not quiete sure where to put it.

This is what the white borders issue looks like:
[SCREENPRINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HADR8.png)

The whole file is a lot of code, I didn't want to crowd this page so the full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/oocwfery/1/

I only put the HTML and the CSS parts where I think the issue might be here. If you'll need the whole code its in the jsfiddle link. I have also commented where the transitions are applied in the code. There is a lot of similar transitions parts like this one in the code on jsfiddle but it would get obnoxious to post it all here?

```
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


  /*----------------------------------
  GRID
  ----------------------------------*/

.all-content{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;

}

ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

li {
position: relative;

}

.squares {
opacity: 0;

}

.grid.visible .squares {
opacity: 1;

}

.squares > li.hidden{
opacity: 0.2;

}


.sq {
float: left;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vw;

}

/*THIS IS WHERE THE TRANSITIONS ARE APPLIED*/
.sq1 {

background: #06465b;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition-property: color;
transition-property: color;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.sq1:before {
background-size: auto 100%;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("../img/kim.jpg");
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
-webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
transform: scaleY(0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
transform-origin: 50% 0;
-webkit-transition-property: transform;
transition-property: transform;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.sq1:hover, .sq1:focus, .sq1:active {
color: white;
}
.sq1:hover:before, .sq1:focus:before, .sq1:active:before {
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
transform: scaleX(1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}

.sq:hover h1,
.sq:hover h2,
.sq:hover h3,
.sq:hover img{
opacity: 1;
}
/*THIS IS WHERE THE TRANSITIONS ARE APPLIED*/
img {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .2s linear, border-radius 1s ease-in 1s;
}
/*THIS IS WHERE THE TRANSITIONS ARE APPLIED*/
h1,
h2,
h3 {
opacity: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
transition: opacity .2s linear, border-radius 1s ease-in 1s;
}
.sq {
  width: 33.3333333vw;
  height: 33.3333333vw;
}
```

HTML (Some parts of the handlebars code doesn't want to come on here for some reason, but those parts are not important I think.)

```
<body>
<div class="all-content type">
        <!-- Gridsystem, data pulled from Json. -->
        <div class="grid page">
        <section class="clearfix">  
            <ul class="squares">
                <script id="projects-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<li data-index="{{id}}" class="{{sqid}}">
                            <img src="{{logo}}">
                            <h3><mark style="background-color: #FFFFFF">{{year}}</mark><br/></h3>
                            <h1><mark style="background-color: #FFFFFF">{{name}}</mark><br/></h1>
                            <h2><mark style="background-color: #FFFFFF">{{type}}</mark></h2>
                        </li>
</script>
            </ul>
        </section>
        </div>
        <!-- Every project has its own page that is hidden, is made visible when clicked on in grid system. -->
        <div class="single-project page">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="popup-detail">

            <h1><mark style="background-color: #FFFFFF">Single project view</mark></h1>
            <h4><mark style="background-color: #FFFFFF">Blurb placeholder</mark></h4>
            <span class="close">×</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="error page">
            <h3>Something went wrong and I'm not sure why.. :o</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Would be forever greatful for any help.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work

Comment: add a working fiddle